# Resize images uploaded on Google Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

We are trying to upload some images to Google Firebase and use a 'serving url' for fast image resize.

The first step was to upload files to Google Firebase. It worked really smooth but now the difficult is part to have an easy way to resize images without creating 5 versions, one for each size.
We researched this topic and found that the previous solutions are deprecated and disabled (Images Go API). Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Related questions:

[Dynamic Image resizing for firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780288/dynamic-image-resizing-for-firebase-storage)

[I want to get serving url for my images on firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932276/i-want-to-get-serving-url-for-my-images-on-firebase-storage)

We did our research on this and really tried to make it work. But as you may expect, we are beginners with Google cloud services.. Any help would me much appreciated.

Our app is a Web App developed using Angular 10, we upload files to Firebase directly from here.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images?

Comment: We've seen this one, but unfortunately: "this extension can create these three resized images then store them in your bucket." and we don't want to create multiple versions of the same file